# Select different product packaging (select between different SKU's)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, selection

I would like to know if there is a possibility to select different product packaging options while viewing one of packaging types. My aim is to display all packaging options separately (to display price for each packaging option) while enabling an option to select different packaging option within product view.

From practical aspect: I have a food supplement with 30 and 60 tablets. I would like to achieve that user could select a product with 60 tablets within viewing product with 30 tablets and vice versa. Also, the price and SKU has to change to the selected product. Is that achievable with Magento? I have tried through bundle options and custom attributes but couldn't find a workable solution for me.

I would be thankful for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to track stock levels for each package size separately, use Configurable Products:

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html

If you don't care about stock levels for each package size, you can use Simple Product and Custom Options, however, Configurable products will give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answer but unfortunately I probably don't use configurable products properly. The problem is, that I have separate simple products with prices configured via automation process which is wired to a physical store. The magento offers me only option to set two different simple products which are covered/bound with the configurable product but within the configurable product, I can only configure price for both of them regardless of the price for any of the simple products. Configuring the price within the configurable product I can set base price and increment for bigger/more expensive packaging. What I saw in some other web stores is the logic that when I select different packaging option the URL in browser redirects to that simple product and displaying it in full/separately. I would like to achieve that functionality. Is that possible in magento? I'm using version 1.9.x.

I could solve this with manually adding links to another packaging in the product description or short description, but if another product is out of stock link would show up anyway.